# Email has been changed notifications

Tags: notifications

Users on my site have been receiving notices that their email has been changed, when in fact no change has been made. Any idea why these are going out and how to prevent it?

Comment: you might have been hacked. check your server logs, your WP directories for recent files changes. have you installed any new plugin recently?

Comment: It appears to be related to a backup using Akeeba. Parent emails were re-synched with students' emails. Our student records contain both and the backup apparently selected student info over parent info.